# How to get attributes of uninitialized instance?

Tags: python, class, object, attributes

Lets say I have a class like below.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

Is there function that will allow me get all the attributes? For example:

```
attributes(Foo)
# [a, b]
```

From what I have been able to find, it seems it is only possible with class attributes.

Comment: You can't do this. Those attributes aren't set for any object that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

No, because those attributes do not actually exist until an instance is created.